# SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". I am not able to understand what does this mean

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, pom.xml, log4j2

I am reading a simple Excel File, the code presumably has no errors in Main.java, I have added the following dependencies in the pom.xml file. I have seen the same problem everywhere, some still are old and unsolved, and most of the solution are deprecated. What should I do now? Any help is appreciated.

This is the Main.java

```java
package com.egi.ExcelReader;


import java.io.*;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class Main {
    public static void readXLSXFile() throws IOException {

        InputStream ip = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\emjueke\\OneDrive - Ericsson\\Documents\\xlreader\\Test.xlsx");
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(ip);

        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        XSSFRow row;
        XSSFCell cell;

        Iterator<Row> rows = sheet.rowIterator();

        while(rows.hasNext()) {

            row = (XSSFRow) rows.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cells = row.cellIterator();

            while(cells.hasNext()) {
                cell = (XSSFCell) cells.next();

                switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                    case STRING -> System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t");
                    case NUMERIC -> System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t");
                    case BOOLEAN -> System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "\t");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        readXLSXFile();
    }
}
```

These are the dependencies in pom.xml. Haven't used a plugin yet.

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

This is the error.
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5CxK.png)

I'm using IntelliJ 2022.3.2 CE, JDK19, Apache POI 5.2.3 and Maven 4.0.0

Comment: As far as I'm aware, Maven 4.0.0 is not released yet: the latest released version is 3.9.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error shows that you have the slf4j interface library added but the slf4j implementation is missing. So you have to add either `slf4j-log4j12` or `slf4j-simple`.

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

OR

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
  <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Where `${slf4j.version}` is the version of your slf4j library.